# How can I get the name of the currently executing Meteor method?

Tags: meteor

Can I get the name of the currently executing Meteor method (from within 
same)? This would be handy for logging.

I inspected `this` inside a Meteor method. It is an instance of `MethodInvocation`, and doesn't appear to have anything useful for figuring out the method name.

Seems like it would be easy enough to add the method name to `MethodInvocation` and callers, but I'm not sure if the maintainers would accept a patch that added a `name` field to every `MethodInvocation` instance.

Crossposted [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/AOHZnEzEExE/2O3orII2pzgJ).

Comment: As a workaround, you could monkey-patch `Meteor.methods` to do this - it could even be a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy with Meteor 1.10.1

You can just use

```
this.name
```

e.g

```
new ValidatedMethod({
  name: "pod.create",
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    stuff: {
      type: String,
    }
}).validator(),
  run(pData) {
    console.log("methodname:" + this.name);
  }
});
```

outputs :

```
I20210126-08:35:30.120(0)? methodname:pod.create
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not ideal, but here's how you could monkey-patch `Meteor.methods` to get this functionality, like stubailo suggests:

```js
var currentMethod = new Meteor.EnvironmentVariable();    

function log(message) {
  var method = currentMethod.get();
  if (method) {
    console.log(method + ": " + message);
  } else {
    console.log(message);
  }
}

var oldMeteorMethods = Meteor.methods;

Meteor.methods = function (object) {
  var methods = {};
  _.each(object, function (func, name) {
    methods[name] = function () {
      var self = this;
      var args = _.toArray(arguments);
      return currentMethod.withValue(name, function() {
        return func.apply(self, args);
      });
    };
  });
  oldMeteorMethods(methods);
}

Meteor.methods({
  example: function (arg1, arg2) {
    log("hello");
    return doSomethingElse(arg1) + arg2;
  }
});

function doSomethingElse(x) {
  log("doSomethingElse called with " + x);
  return x * 2;
}

// Meteor.call("example", 5, 6) logs:
// "example: hello"
// "example: doSomethingElse called with 5"
```

If you prefer not to monkey-patch:

```js
defineMethods = function (object) {
  var methods = {};
  _.each(object, function (func, name) {
    methods[name] = function () {
      var self = this;
      var args = _.toArray(arguments);
      return currentMethod.withValue(name, function() {
        return func.apply(self, args);
      });
    };
  });
  Meteor.methods(methods);
}

defineMethods({
  example: function (arg1, arg2) {
    log("hello");
    return doSomethingElse(arg1) + arg2;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reworked a little bit @user337's answer. Now you can use `@name` inside method function.
Add this to server code (coffeescript):

```
currentMethod = new Meteor.EnvironmentVariable()
oldMeteorMethods = Meteor.methods

Meteor.methods = (object) ->
    methods = {}
    _.each object, (func, name) ->
        methods[name] = ->
            args = _.toArray(arguments)
            this.name = name
            currentMethod.withValue name, =>
                func.apply this, args
    oldMeteorMethods methods
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents, for a fully working monkey patched version (without underscore).
Inside method function you can use this.currentMethodName now.

```
Meteor.methods = (object) => {
    let methods = {};
    let keys = Object.keys(object)
    keys.forEach(key => {
        methods[key] = function () {
            let self = this;
            let args = [...arguments];
            self.currentMethodName = key
            return object[key].apply(self, args);
        }
    })
    oldMeteorMethods(methods);
}
```